# How to make links from the beginning to the end of the div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How to make my links across the col-md-2 when is a:hover?

The look of my links:
[image]

The look of the links I want: 
[image]

My code:

```css
.sidebar {
        background-color: lightgray;
    }
      
    .sidebar a {
        display: block;
        color: black;
        padding: 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .sidebar a.active {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
    }
      
    .sidebar a:hover:not(.active) {
        background-color: #555;
        color: white;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 sidebar">
            <a>Link 1</a>
            <a>Link 2</a>
            <a>Link 3</a>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-md-10">

        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: is not clear what you mean with "across the col-md-2 when is a:hover"

Comment: That my links are from the beginning to the end of the div size col-md-2

Comment: Is this bootstrap? If so, please tag as such.

Comment: Yes, this is bootstrap. I added bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `padding:0 !important;` for `.sidebar`

```css
.sidebar {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.sidebar a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.sidebar a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 sidebar">
      <a>Link 1</a>
      <a>Link 2</a>
      <a>Link 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ist !Important really needed?
I try the same without on Codepen.io an in runs without.
https://codepen.io/tevsa/pen/Ydzxdg

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: It looks like you are using Bootstrap 4. Your problem is that in Bootstrap the .col-md-2 class has padding-left and padding-right of 15px. In order to get your links to stretch all the way across, you need to override that. There are a few ways you can do that, but here is how I would do it. I would add an inline style directly to the div you create and change `<div class="col-md-2 sidebar">` to be `<div class="col-md-2 sidebar" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px">`

Comment: Did not help, no effect.

Comment: What is the CSS for col-md-2, row, and container-fluid? Those are having some sort of effect on your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this structure. It will be better if you add `<div class="sidebar">` line inside `.col-md-2`, not with that. Check my code and demo.

```css
.sidebar {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
      
.sidebar a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
    
.sidebar a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
      
.sidebar a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="sidebar">
            <a>Link 1</a>
            <a>Link 2</a>
            <a>Link 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```